# Is it possible to list the changelists that have been integrated to a workspace?

Tags: perforce

In perforce, is it possible to get a list of the change lists that have been integrated into a workspace but not committed?

Comment: I don't think so... You could have already integrated only some files, corresponding to incomplete integrated changelists, and leaving incomplete changelists to integrate. It looks like "finding the label which was used to synchronize the client" (which I think you can't).

Comment: Maybe you could write a script comparing the result of `p4 interchanges` in the current client, with the result of `p4 interchanges` in another client (in which the integrations are not pending)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `p4 resolved`? It won't tell you exactly which changelists, but it will tell you which file versions, which can then be pretty easily tracked back to changelists.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'm going to wrap the process up in a perl script but this is exactly what I was hoping for.